# How to set status when click login in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, hook

I want to create Drawer when after login. I'm not sure what I'm going to do is right.
If it's correct, how do I get back to handling setIsLogin in the App.js file?

**Myapp.js**

```
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';

export default function App() {

  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);

  if(isLogin){
    return(
      //create Drawer here
    )

  }else{
    return(
      <LoginScreen/>
    )
  }
}
```

**LoginScreen.js**

```
const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    
    const _onPress = async() => {

        const payload = {
            username:username,
            password:password
        }

    };

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _onPress()} >
                <Text style={styles.textButton}>Log in</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

If i misunderstand Or is there a better way, please advise me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, this should work:

You can pass the setState as reference from parent to child, update the state on child and it will rerender parent.

```
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';

export default function App() {

  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);

  if(isLogin){
    return(
      //create Drawer here
    )

  }else{
    return(
      <LoginScreen setLoginStatus = {setIsLogin}/>
    )
  }
}


const LoginScreen = ({navigation, setLoginStatus}) => {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  
  const _onPress = async() => 
  {

      const payload = {
          username:username,
          password:password
      }

      setLoginStatus(true) //Or false depending on the payload response.

  };

  return (
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _onPress()} >
              <Text style={styles.textButton}>Log in</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen;
```